# PUT mapping error elasticsearch with rest client : Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:

Tags: rest, http, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, put

[image]

As you can see in the attachement, i want to create a mapping called movie but i have the following error:
Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "movie":{
      "properties": {
        "year": {
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

on elasticearch v 7.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to create a mapping using a type, in your case `movie`, but since version 7.0 the mappings are [typeless](https://www.elastic.co/blog/moving-from-types-to-typeless-apis-in-elasticsearch-7-0) and you can't create mappings using a type anymore.

You should use the following mapping.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "year": {
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will create a mapping for the field `year` with the date `date`.